# Prove that correlation coefficients are equal between two random variable equations

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that correlation coefficient between X and Y is (, ) and a, b, c, d are constants, prove that the correlation coefficient between U =  +  and  =  +  is equal to (, ) = (, )

My take on the problem:

Prove that $p(U, V)=p(X, Y)$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)=E[X Y]-E[X] \cdot E[Y] \\
&\rho(U, V)=p(X, Y) \\
&\frac{\operatorname{Cov}(U, V)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(U) \operatorname{Var}(V)}}=\frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)}} \\
&\frac{E[U V]-E[U] E[V]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(U) \operatorname{Var}(V)}}=\frac{E[X Y]-E[X] E[Y]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(U)}}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{a c \cdot E[X Y]+a d E[X]+b c E[Y]-E[X] \cdot a E[Y] \cdot c}{a c \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)}} \\
&=\frac{E[X Y]-E[X] E[Y]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(Y)}} \\
&\frac{E[X Y]+\frac{a d}{a c} E[X]+\frac{b c}{a c} E[Y]-E[Y] E[Y]}{a c / a c} \\
&=E[X Y]-E[X] E[Y] \\
&\frac{d}{c} E[X]+\frac{b}{a} E[Y]=0 \\
&\frac{d}{c} E[X]=-\frac{b}{a} E[Y]
\end{aligned}
$$

How to get to a conclusion from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A huge problem with what you're doing is you're assuming what you want to show to start with, which is a bad practice. You should also make use of covariance [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties) to make your life easier.

Let $U = aX + b$ and $V = cY + d$. Then
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(U, V) &= \text{Cov}(aX + b, cY + d) \\
&= \text{Cov}(aX, cY)  \\
&= ac\text{Cov}(X, Y)\text{.}
\end{align}
Furthermore, we have that
$$\text{Var}(U) = \text{Var}(aX + b) = \text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$$
and similarly, $\text{Var}(V) = c^2\text{Var}(Y)$.

Do not forget that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, hence

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{\text{Var}(U)} = \sqrt{a^2\text{Var}(X)} = |a|\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)} \\
&\sqrt{\text{Var}(V)} = \sqrt{c^2\text{Var}(Y)} = |c|\sqrt{\text{Var}(Y)}
\end{align}

Hence the correlation coefficient
\begin{align}
\rho(U, V) &= \dfrac{\text{Cov}(U, V)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(U)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(V)}} \\
&= \dfrac{ac\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{|a|\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)} \cdot |c|\sqrt{\text{Var}(Y)}} \\
&= \dfrac{ac}{|a||c|} \cdot \dfrac{\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(Y)}} \\
&= \dfrac{ac}{|a||c|} \cdot \rho(X, Y)\text{.}
\end{align}

We now have to consider $\dfrac{ac}{|a||c|}$.

Obviously if both $a, c$ are positive, we have $|a||c| = ac$, so $\dfrac{ac}{|a||c|} = 1$.

Suppose, without loss of generality, that $a$ is negative and $c$ is positive. Then $|a| = -a$ by [definition of the absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties) and $|c| = c$. Hence $$\dfrac{ac}{|a||c|} = \dfrac{ac}{(-a)c} = -1\text{.}$$

If both $a$ and $c$ are negative, then
$$\dfrac{ac}{|a||c|} = \dfrac{ac}{(-a)(-c)} = \dfrac{ac}{ac} = 1\text{.}$$

Thus, we conclude:

$\fbox{If both $a$ and $c$ are of the same sign, then $\rho(U, V) = \rho(X, Y)$. Otherwise, $\rho(U, V) = -\rho(X, Y)$.}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use $\rho(X,Y)=Cov(\frac{X-\mathbb{E}X}{\sigma(X)},\frac{Y-\mathbb{E}Y}{\sigma(Y)})$.

Should be a one line exercise. Here $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. Explore the properties of variance and mean value.

> $\rho(aX+b,cY+d)=Cov(\frac{aX+b-a\mathbb{E}X-b}{\sigma(aX+b)},\frac{cY+d-c\mathbb{E}Y-d}{\sigma(cY+d)})=Cov(\frac{a(X-\mathbb{E}X)}{|a|\sigma(X)},\frac{c(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)}{|c|\sigma(Y)})=\rho(X,Y)$